# ping wsl2 ubuntu from windows host

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ping, wsl2

I have a Ubuntu instance running through WSL2. I want to ping this instance from the host machine and unfortunately, it fails. However, I can ping from ubuntu to windows.

- win: `ipconfig` returns 192.168.1.254

  - ubuntu > win: ping 192.168.1.254 works
- ubuntu: `ip addr show eth0` returns `inet 172.20.139.164`, and `inet 172.20.143.255`

  - win > ubuntu: ping both IP addresses from above fails